# Why am I getting DeprecationWarning while html form submit?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a html form which sends text-area value to a django view. The view then communicates this data to `google-drive` api.  I am getting following message on terminal

`C:\Python27\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py:127: DeprecationWarning:`Creating streaming
responses with `HttpResponse` is deprecated. Use `StreamingHttpResponse` instead
 if you need the streaming behavior.
  for data in self.result:

Earlier I was using HttpResponse in django view but even though I changed it to StreamingResponseObject I am getting same warning.

It seems from the logs that form submit does not go till django view and the request dies earlier with above message. 
My view is as follows:

```
def main(request):
    if request.POST and request.POST['form'] == 'Save':
        return save(request)

def save(request):
    if request.POST:
        try:
            user = request.user
            social = user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2')
            code = request.POST['hiddentextarea']
            filename = request.POST['filename']
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                f.write(code)
            storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential')
            credentials = storage.get()
            http = httplib2.Http()
            http = credentials.authorize(http)
            service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
            resource = createOrUpdateFile(service, filename)
            t = loader.get_template('main.html')
            c = RequestContext(request,{
                    'input' : code,
                    'fileid' : resource['title']
                })
            return StreamingHttpResponse(t.render(c))
        except (AccessTokenRefreshError, Exception):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('../')
```

My form is as follows:

```
<form action="/main/" method="post" onsubmit="return copyeditorcontent()">
{% csrf_token %} 
<div id='codeinput' >
<div id='inputlabel'>
    <text>Code</text>
</div>
<div id="editor" name='editor'>
</div>

<div id='buttons'>
  <button id='runbutton' type="submit" value="Run" name="form">Run</button>
  <button id='savebutton' type="submit" value="Save" name="form" >Save to Google Drive</button>
</div>
<textarea id='hiddentextarea' name='hiddentextarea' style='opacity:0;'></textarea>
<div id='filenamesection' style="">
<input id='filename' name='filename' type='hidden' value='{% if fileid %}{{ fileid  }}{% endif %}'></input>
</div>

<script src="../static/src/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/github");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/python");
    {% if input %}
    editor.setValue('{{ input|escapejs }}');
    var totalLines = editor.session.getLength();
    editor.gotoLine(totalLines);
    {% endif %}
    var filename = document.getElementById('filename').value;

    if (filename != ''){
        document.getElementById('savebutton').innerHTML = 'Save';
        }
    else{
        document.getElementById('savebutton').innerHTML = 'Save to Google Drive';
        }
</script>

</div>
</form>
```

I get this warning only when I am pressing **'Save to Google Drive'** button. Please help me here.

Comment: Please show the view that is causing the deprecation warning.

Comment: If the request is not going till view then what's the use of showing view? anyways I have added the view. Please check

Comment: The form is just text, it doesn't return a response, streaming or otherwise, so it isn't going to show what's going on by itself.

Comment: Use the warnings module to raise an error where the `DeprecationWarning` occurs by adding the following two lines to the top of your view: `import warnings`, `warnings.simplefilter('error', DeprecationWarning)`. This will give you a full traceback of the code that is raising the deprecation warning. At the moment, you don't know what is raising the warning in `wsgiref.handlers`.